# transfer data from one component to another angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components, implementation, data-transfer

I have **component A** which fires MatDialog

```
  openDialog(): void {
   // console.log('The dialog was opened');

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PicuploadComponent, {
      width: '1000px',
      //data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
// I want to get data from upload response here! **res**
    });
  }
```

This component fires **PicuploadComponent** where I upload image and receive response with some data

```
onUpload() {
  const fd = new FormData(); 
  fd.append('image', this.selectedFile);
  this.service.uploadImage(fd).subscribe(
    (res:any)=>
    {
      console.log(res) ;
      this.dialogRef.close();
    },    
  );
}
```

Comment: I already described this in my answer to your previous question... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57822253/2352314

Comment: This is a duplicate question!

see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664974/how-to-pass-data-to-dialog-of-angular-material-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in **PicuploadComponent**:

```
this.dialogRef.close(res);
```

access to res in **component A**:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you close dialog.

```
this.dialogRef.close({data:'data'});
```

When dialog completely closed then.

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PicuploadComponent, dialogConfig).afterClosed()
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Let me know If you have any query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the result from your `uploadImage` call to the `this.dialogRef.close()` method. Please see the example in their documentation, https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview